# SQLite, Filling in NULL with TEXT value

Tags: sqlite

I have a table with 2 columns and 9 Rows, FirstName and LastName.
All rows of FirstName Column IS NOT NULL, but 1 row of LastName is NULL.

How would I put a value into NULL?

This is the Code I have:

```
SELECT Emp1.FirstName Employee, Emp2.FirstName Manager
FROM Employee Emp1
LEFT JOIN Employee Emp2 ON Emp2.EmployeeID = Emp1.ReportsTo;
```

Which produces:

[image]

I have tried IFNULL, but it didn't seem to work.

```
SELECT Emp1.FirstName Employee, Emp2.FirstName Manager, IFNULL('No Manager')
FROM Employee Emp1
LEFT JOIN Employee Emp2 ON Emp2.EmployeeID = Emp1.ReportsTo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for ISNULL is slightly different. Try this:

```
SELECT Emp1.FirstName Employee, IFNULL(Emp2.FirstName, 'No Manager') as Manager
FROM Employee Emp1
LEFT JOIN Employee Emp2 ON Emp2.EmployeeID = Emp1.ReportsTo;
```

Please let me know if I can help you further.

Comment: Worked like a charm, I was having trouble with what values needed to go in the () after IFNULL. Thank you.

Comment: @user430574 I am happy that I could help.